# How to disable SPAN tag through javascript

Tags: javascript

For example, I have a spans:

```
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span>...
```

... and so on

And click function (works perfectly fine):

```
var on = document.querySelectorAll(".alphStyle");    
for (var i = 0; i < on.length; i++){
        on[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            var whatLetter = this.innerHTML;
            var num = 0;
            var trueCount = 0;
            for (num = 0; num < guessWord.length; num++) {
                if (whatLetter == guessWord.charAt(num)) {
                    secretW.getElementsByClassName("lineStyle")[num].innerHTML = whatLetter;
                    this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(65,208,65)";
                    trueCount++;
                    trueCount2++;
                } 
            }
            if (trueCount == 0) {
                mistake();
                this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,100,100)";
            }
            this.disabled = true;//this one doesn't work

        });
    }
```

It works perfectly fine, except that I want it to disable spans i already clicked. Is it possible? What code should I add here?

Comment: What do you mean disable?

Comment: These spans has click function. I want to disable exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set/check Data attribute once you click a span.

```
var on = document.querySelectorAll(".alphStyle");    
for (var i = 0; i < on.length; i++){
    on[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      if(this.dataset.disabled!="yes") {
        var whatLetter = this.innerHTML;
        var num = 0;
        var trueCount = 0;
        for (num = 0; num < guessWord.length; num++) {
            if (whatLetter == guessWord.charAt(num)) {
                secretW.getElementsByClassName("lineStyle")[num].innerHTML = whatLetter;
                this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(65,208,65)";
                trueCount++;
                trueCount2++;
            } 
        }
        if (trueCount == 0) {
            mistake();
            this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,100,100)";
        }
        this.dataset.disabled = "yes";
      }
    });
}
```

Here is a working example, https://jsfiddle.net/yd7w62e6/1/

Comment: Nope, didn't help

Comment: Can you be please more specific? @bleatinterteiment

Comment: I have a lot of clickable spans. Each of them run the function I showed. If it's possible, I want to disable all clicked spans, so they couldn't run that function no more, because it ruins my calculations, which are really important.

Comment: You can always set data attribute disabled to `true` for the checked/clicked ones. And in your main function just skip those who has `data-disabled=true` Can you please create a fiddle for it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, your code worked, I just didn't understood you right. Thanks for working example!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to prevent future clicks from triggering your click handler, you can remove the click handler using `removeEventListener()`. To do so, you will need to assign your listener to a variable that you can reference later.

```
var on = document.querySelectorAll(".alphStyle");    

var handler = function(){
    // ...
    this.removeEventHandler('click', handler);
};
for (var i = 0; i < on.length; i++){
    on[i].addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

Comment: My goal is to disable exactly clicked "span". So if its clicked again, function does not run. Hope you got me right